# Should one add a 'thank you' comment to a helpful answer, or not?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the etiquette about leaving short thank-you comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments)

It's my instinct to say 'thanks!' when I've been helped, so I like to say thanks in a comment after answers I find useful. There is usually no other content in these comments. I'm wondering if such verbal thanks may be seen as irritating clutter on this site; or if it's a benign habit.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments addresses what you're after, right?